# Reporting with Jfreechart?

Tags: jfreechart

I have created a chart using jfreechart library. I have the data set that use to create the graph. Is there any way I can get a report of the data in a tabular form directly from the jfreechart chart object.. Or any other ways where i can create report using jfreechart

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Assuming an [`XYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset.html) for example, one approach is to extend [`AbstractXYDataset`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/AbstractXYDataset.html) and implement [`TableModel`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html). Then you can construct a [`JTable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html), which is easy to render or print.